# Other .md files not appearing in Visual Studio Online

Tags: markdown, azure-devops, welcome-file

I am wondering if this is a bug. I have a Readme.md file showing in VSO.

However my other files dont show. One of them is called test.md.

Here are some screen shots:
[image]
[image]

any ideas?

Comment: Just a note that this still doesn't work. I added a ReadMe2.md file and committed it. I still can see anything but the default Readme.md.